# Baseline creation interrupted

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I tried to create a baseline today and ClearCase Explorer crashed (seemed to be after it was finished, but evidently it wasn't.)

I tried to recreate the baseline and it gives me an error saying there are some that are "in_progress" so it can not proceed.

I removed the baseline, and I am trying to remove the "in_progress" label types.
When I remove the lbtype, it says that a directory is locked.

I did an lslock -all and removed the locks on a project and a baseline and now there is nothing listed when I do an lslock -all.

I tried to remove the "in_progress" lbtype and it is still saying that something is locked.  Is there another way to find out what is preventing it from working?

I know this may be confusing, so if any clarification is needed, I am willing to update my question.

> "ct lslock -all"
>
> --09-09T09:47  USER     lock project "XXXXXXX" (locked)
>   "Locked for all users.    Project locked for future changes as released."
>
> --09-20T09:56  USER     lock baseline "XXXXXXXXX" (locked)
>   "Locked for all users."

(removed locks)

"ct lslock -all" shows nothing

> "rmtype -rmall lbtype:BASELINE_in_progress@\VOB
>
> There are 1228 labels of type "BASELINE_in_progress".
>
> Remove labels?  [no] yes
>
> cleartool: Error: Lock (obsolete) on directory element prevents
>   operation "remove label".
>
> cleartool: Error: Unable to remove label type "BASELINE_in_progress".

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message stating that "something" is locked?

Comment: SO you have directories which are locked. try lslock i your view, adding the root directory of the component, to check if it detects anything. (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lslock.htm)

Comment: @VonC - I assumed that the '-all' would list all locked files.  However, it won't list obsolete files without the '-obsolete' option.  Now it lists a LOT of files (under one locked directory) that are locked.  Is there a way to do this recursively or another easy way to unlock all of these temporarily?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=13758105: you could pipe the result of the lslock to an unlock command in order to unlock sequentially all the obsolete (hence locked) files.

Comment: Or you can use find: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=14001812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual error message is

```
possible stranded temporary lbtype name found: "`abaselinexxx.yyyy_in_progress`".
```

The idea is to:

- remove all the _inprogress types in the vob(s) involved by the UCM components

```
$ ct rmtype -rmall lbtype:abaselinexxx.yyyy_in_progress@\\avob
There are 1690 labels of type "abaselinexxx.yyyy_in_progress".
Remove labels?  [no] yes
```

- promote the baseline into a fully labelled one:

```
ct chbl -full -nc baseline:abaselinexxx.yyyy@\apvob
```

The locks which could prevent those operations to complete are:

- on the lbtype
- on the vob (ie the vob itself could be locked)
- on the pvob (the pvob or one of its admin pvob could be locked)

---

Few remarks, from the comments:

- `cleartool lslock -all` won't display *obsolete* files ("obsolete" being one form of locking): `cleartool lslock -all -obsolete` will.
- to unlock a set of locked files, you have a choice between `for` and `cleartool find -exec` commands.

> #### Windows

```
for /f "delims==" %x in ('cleartool lslock -all -obsolete -fmt "%Xn\n"') do cleartool unlock "%x"
```

#### Unix, in view context...

```
cleartool lslock -all -obsolete -fmt "%Xn\n" | xargs -i{}
cleartool unlock %x
```

Note that a `cleartool find` would unlock *everything* under a certain path.
If you know that path (and all -- or most of all -- its content) is locked, then it can work:

```
ct find /path/to/a/locked/directory -exec '/usr/atria/bin/cleartool unlock  "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

Comment: It let me create a new baseline with the same name and promote it to full.  However, it is still giving me the errors that something is locked when I try to remove the _in_progress labels.  I will update my question with the full errors.