# Why is a label applied to my version when baseline is incremental

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a version of an element in an integration stream, that looks like this:

```
.\vob\compdir\example.cpp@@\main\example_is\1
```

This version has a multitude of labels applied to it.
When I look up the baselines, which this labels belong too, then I see it is a incrementally labeled baseline. (For the ones I looked up)

Reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696598/what-is-the-difference-between-full-baseline-and-incremental-baseline-in-clearca), I thought that when creating an incremental baseline, labels only get applied to versions, that have changed since the last full baseline.
But in my case all these labels are on the same version.
What is my missunderstanding here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and understood, that this was a missunderstanding.
So what I thought was, that when a version doesn't change it should not get a label, when I create a incremental baseline.

**BUT:**

Labels get applied to each version, that was changed since the last **full** baseline. So even if the version did not change from one incremental baseline to the next, it still gets the label for the new baseline. Because the 'current' version is not the same as the version in the last **full** baseline.

Edit:

I even wrote 'full baseline' in my question but did not understand the concept

Answer (score 1):

I usually see this case only when an incremental baseline has been changed into a full baseline, using [`cleartool chbl`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chbl.htm) (as [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11395703/6309))

That would trigger a label applied on *all* versions of the UCM component.

The other case, as [explained here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/creating-identical-baseline-ucm), is when using [`cleartool mkbl -identical`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm), where you would create an incremental baseline... identical to one which was full.

Comment: Sadly neither of the cases you mentioned fits here. The baseline is incrementally labeled and was never changed, also it was not created using the flag -identical.

However the baseline was created indirectly by creating a composite baseline for a rootless component. Could that play a role ?

Comment: @andymeissner An incremental composite baseline should generate only incremental baselines on the dependent components. Note sure what happens though in case of a parasite baseline (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17623872/6309).

Comment: It was just a missunderstand of the concept of an incremental baseline. I added an answer